# Dell M4800 Ubuntu 16.04 freeze graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, dell

**Update**

I have installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 16.04 I am now using the nouveau display driver. So far things have been stable but things only seem to crash when my computer is plugged into my dock which has two monitors.

Downside I can't play any games :(

==============================================================================
**Original Post**

I am running a Dell M4800 running Ubuntu 16.04. Occasionally the graphics freeze, but the mouse still can move.

Hardware information is in the link below

Additional Symptoms

1. I can't open a terminal windows
2. I can switch to another terminal but it hangs. Sometimes it just spits out a kernel error about the kernel hanging for longer than 120 seconds. I cannot login to the machine in the other terminals.
3. The hard drive light seems to be working as normal.

I think it's a graphic problem. I am running NVIDIA 361 drivers. I have tried 352 driver, but I still had the same problem. I tried switch back to Nouveau, but I can't login after I install the driver.

If anyone can give me any idea how I can go about debugging this problem that would be helpful

`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

**-Display-**

```
Vendor      : NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer        : Quadro K2100M/PCIe/SSE2
Version     : 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42
Direct Rendering        : Yes
```

**-PCI Devices-**

```
Host bridge     : Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Communication controller        : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Ethernet controller     : Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Audio device        : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
ISA bridge      : Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
RAID bus controller     : Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
SMBus       : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
VGA compatible controller       : NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Audio device        : NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
Network controller      : Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
SD Host controller      : O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Added it above but here it is again 
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Dell GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: How do you get to install the Wireless card?

Comment: I just installed ubuntu 16.04 it should automatically find the wireless card. You have to make sure the computer boots up with the wireless card enabled. That is make sure the wireless switch is enabled. When the computer boots. If you are upgrading make sure not to upgrade the wireless card